# Setting padding to UILabel crops characters

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uilabel, drawtextinrect

I'm adding padding to UILabel

```
public partial class MessageLabel : UILabel
    {
        public MessageLabel(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public override void DrawText(CoreGraphics.CGRect rect)
        {
            UIEdgeInsets insets = new UIEdgeInsets() { Bottom = 5, Top = 5, Left = 5, Right = 5 };
            base.DrawText(insets.InsetRect(rect));
        }
    }
```

Padding are added well, but last line is cropped, due to extra empty space I added... If I increate height with 10 in this methods, padding are added only at the top of label.

with paddings  screen 1 - looks nice, but missing words:
[image]

without passings screen 2 - show whole message:
[image]

Any solution?

Comment: Are you using numberOfLines = 0?

Comment: @DanielQ yes, I do

Comment: the solution provided by @DanielQ works on iOS,  but there is something wrong with xamarin.ios, I got the same test result as you described in question,  to fit this problem, maybe you should set height manually according to the text content. `CGSize size = label.Text.StringSize(label.Font, new CGSize(widthConstraint.Constant - 50, 9999),UILineBreakMode.WordWrap);heightConstraint.Constant = size.Height;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    private var topInset: CGFloat = 5
    private var bottomInset: CGFloat = 5
    private var leftInset: CGFloat = 5
    private var rightInset: CGFloat = 5

    override func drawTextInRect(rect: CGRect) {

      let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: topInset, left: leftInset, bottom: bottomInset, right: rightInset)
          super.drawTextInRect(UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))
      }

override public var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    var intrinsicSuperViewContentSize = super.intrinsicContentSize
    intrinsicSuperViewContentSize.height += topInset + bottomInset
    intrinsicSuperViewContentSize.width += leftInset + rightInset
    return intrinsicSuperViewContentSize
}
```

Comment: I need padding for UILabel at least 5 px

Comment: seriously ? do you think that there is any difference between your answer and my question ? :(

Comment: What's this "public override void DrawText(CoreGraphics.CGRect rect)" ?

Comment: func drawTextInRect(rect: CGRect)

Comment: Are you using constraints?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155307/discussion-between-danielq-and-nininea).